# Appending src attribute to iframe is downloading the file and the file is not displaying in the html page

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a list of file names which i fetch from my backend and rendering it in the ejs file. I have an button to view the files. When clicking the button i get the file from the public folder and appending it to the src attribute in the iframe which is in a popup. The file is not displaying in the iframe and instead it is downloading. Why the file is not displaying properly and why it is downloading the file?

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="contractPop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
       labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="titleModal">Contract</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="container">
         <iframe id="contractFile" src="" width="500" height="600" frameborder="0"> 
         </iframe>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

And the function appending source to iframe is

```
     function showFile(index){
        let filename = document.getElementById('filename'+index).innerText;
        let src = "files/company_contract/" + filename;
        $('#contractPop').modal('show')
        $('#contractFile').attr('src', src)
     }
```

Comment: If your browser doesn't support file extension then it will start downloading file.

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar I am checking in google chrome browser. I don't know if it supports or not.

Comment: It is   contract.pdf_12.  _12 is the Id of the client.

Comment: `.pdf_12` is not valid extension for any browser. Don't change file extensions. Changing filename is better idea. Eg. `contract_12.pdf`. just do some improvement on server side code

Comment: **@RiteshKhandekar** Yes. It worked. I just changed the filename and checked. It is working now. Now am able to view the file. Thanks a lot **@RiteshKhandekar**